# Switch raspbian to 64bit

Tags: raspbian, debian-based

I switched my raspian to 64bit by adding `arm_64bit=1` to `/boot/config.txt`. It worked in that sense, that the kernel now is 64bit.

When I want to install packages (docker in my case), I want to use it the 64bit version, but it installs the 32bit version. As it turns out, the package manager still is set to 32bit:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
armhf
```

How can I make the package manager install 64bit packages?

Comment: This is a sysadmin question, not about programming.  Voted to migrate to https://superuser.com/.  Might fit even better on https://linux.stackexchange.com/ where there might be a duplicate Debian Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
i386
# dpkg --add-architecture arm64
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
amd64
# apt-get update
# apt-get download gcc-4.6-base:arm64 libgcc1:arm64 libc6:arm64 \
          libselinux1:arm64 zlib1g:arm64 libbz2-1.0:arm64 dpkg:arm64
# dpkg -i gcc-4.6-base*.deb libgcc*.deb libc*.deb libselinux*.deb \
          libbz2*.deb zlib*.deb dpkg*.deb
$ dpkg --print-architecture
arm64
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

Some of your packages are then amd64, but most will remain i386. apt-get upgrade will take care of some packages, apt-get -f install will repair some of errors, but still most packages will remain i386. If you want to cope with this, then skip the tricky part ;)

Using `dpkg --get-selections | grep :i386` will return all your packages, that you will still have to migrate.

My next idea was to do:

```
# apt-get install `dpkg --get-selections \
  | grep i386 \
  | awk {'gsub(/:i386/, ":amd64"); print $1'}`
```

But it turned out to be a bad idea: some packages are not available in amd64 (e.g. libc6-i686), apt-get will be confused, and a lot of packages will be installed in both versions. A lot of manual work in aptitude is to be done.

Comment: While this answer may give the right hints, it is mixing up arm32 and i386 (as well as amd64 and arm64). The Pi has an arm64 CPU.